# How to iterate over MultiIndex levels in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I often have MultiIndex indices and I'd like to iterate over groups where higher level indices are equal. It basically looks like

```
from random import choice
import pandas as pd
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame([choice([1, 2, 3]) for _ in range(N)],
                  columns=["A"],
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(choice("ab"), choice("cd"), choice("de")) 
                                                   for _ in range(N)]))

for idx in zip(df.index.get_level_values(0), df.index.get_level_values(1)):
    df_select = df.ix[idx]
```

Is there a way to do the for loop iteration more neatly?

Answer (score 17):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).  The index of the `df_select` view includes the first two level values, but otherwise is similar to your example.

```
for idx, df_select in df.groupby(level=[0, 1]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to groupby logic you can use a lambda function, which has the advantage of not having to specify the number of levels, i.e. it will pick all levels except the very last one:

```
for idx in df.index.map(lambda x: x[:-1]):
 df_select=df.ix[idx]
```

Comment: I believe this answer to be wrong as it doesn't iterate over the "unique" groups of the first `df.index.nlevels-1` levels, but iterates over all rows just filtering by the first `df.index.nlevels-1` levels.  In this way, if each nth level had 10 unique index values, it would select each unique `df_select` ten times.