# Percent Change in for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe where I've set both the District and the Year as a multilevel index.  I want to calculate the percentage change for each column ('DEM', 'REP', etc) for each district for each year.

[image]

I have consulted [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139121/how-to-iterate-over-multiindex-levels-in-pandas/34139354) and tried using the following code:

```
for idx, districts_bydistrict_select in districts_bydistrict.groupby(level=[0, 1]):
    y = districts_bydistrict.pct_change()
    print(pd.DataFrame(y))
```

However it is not recognizing to start the pct_change() calculation over when there is a new District.  I realize I am probably missing some part of the for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify the level in your `groupby`.

```
districts_bydistrict.groupby(level='Year').pct_change()
```

You can unstack the districts so that you just have time in the index, compute `pct_change`, and then restack the districts.

```
districts_bydistrict.unstack('DISTRICTS').pct_change().stack()
```